# Print Devanagari Text on openCV2 Webcam

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, python-unicode

I have been trying to print Devanagari Text on CV2 webcam using-

```
 cv2.putText(img, '%s' % (res), (100,400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 4, (255,255,255), 4)
 cv2.putText(img, '(score = %.5f)' % (float(score)), (100,450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255))
```

To print Devnagari, I am passing unicode characters, however, in the output window, I am getting only "?". I guess cv2.putText cannot read all unicode characters.

Expected Output :

```
ड, score = x.xxx
```

The unicode for ड is u'\u0921'

```
 ??? , score = x.xxx
```

Any help would be of great help. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Those fonts are fairly limited. You'll need to use a different method to render text onto an image.

Comment: Is there any other method ?

Comment: If OpenCV was built with the Qt HighGUI backend, there's [`addText`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga4e2751b94f709c848f0658d78007e449) that might do it -- AFAIK it lets you use any system font. The `ImageDraw` module from PIL also lets you render text. I'm quite sure there are other options as well.